# Is this relationship between variables linear?

Tags: multiple-regression, data-visualization, linear-model, scatterplot, linearity

I have four research questions and all of them has the same main "independent variable", as such the relationship between x and y1, y2, y3, y4. This is not a multivariate analysis, I am just interested to know the impact of one variable X on loan term, interest, default etc. as separate multiple linear regression (one main variable and several control variables). I use a filtered dataset of repaid and defaulted loans only for testing loan default (y) (excluding currently active loans) and the X variable has only values of 5% and 10% (last photo). As for the data for other research questions (interest, loan term), around 30 observations out of the whole data set of 950k observations is 2% and the rest takes value of 5% or 10%. I am confused if the relationship between them is linear because the data points are centered around either 5% or 10%, not scattered. I use scatter plots to identify if the variables X and Y are linear before conducting multiple linear regression. The graph, all of them especially last one I am unsure if it is linear. Please advise. enter image description hereimage 1[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is lots of overplotting in these scatterplots. Often, when we don't want to assume the relationship between predictor and outcome is linear we use splines. In your case however, I'm not sure that's very interesting or relevant. These loan products haven't been offered at any other rates than 5%, 10% and rarely (some time ago?) at 2%. So I have doubts why build a model that can generate a prediction for, say, 4%.

Comment: The purpose of the model is to infer causal relationship, as such will an increase in x cause an increase or decrease in y (linear regression) or event of y (when y=1 in logistic). The variable X is actually a requirement that is predetermined, so each loan falls in either 2%,, 5%, or 10%. but majority of loans fall under the category of 0.05  and 0.10. Since this variable is relatively a new concept, I am interested to know what is the impact of such requirement on default, interest rates, loan maturity etc. continued below

Comment: I want to run  a multiple regression to test this relationship because although X is my main variable of interest, I have several control variables. I understand linearity between x and y is a assumption before running a multiple regression, so I want to confirm if Iam choosing the right model to test it. Are these graphs/ relationships between variables linear?

Comment: You have observational data only? I don't see how you can make a strong causal argument. This might be interesting to read: [Designing great data products](https://www.oreilly.com/radar/drivetrain-approach-data-products/).

Comment: I personally won't be proposing any model that claims to make predictions for what happens outside of x = 5% and x = 10%. And even for 2% I would be very cautious. So no, I don't think you have the data to claim anything particular about the relationship between $x$ and $y$: is it linear or not.